# Flex Tree leaf-element highlighting while drag&drop

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, tree, tilelist

i have TileList from which i'm dragging some stuff(image) to Tree (something like dragging sounds into playlist in iTunes), but when i can drop this stuff, i see only underline, this mean i can drop it only under or above some leaf-element in that Tree. How can i force it to hide this black underline and highlight leaf-element to which i wanna drop my stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The last example on this page has pretty much exactly what you're looking for.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/working_with_tree/

Comment: yeah adobe likes to move their stuff around all willy nilly. This might be it, but since I linked that over a year ago I can't be sure.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstarts/working_with_tree_controls.html